# How validate select class="form-control"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model:

```
[Display(Name = "FamilyStatus")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is required")]
public string r_familyStatus { get; set; }
```

and View:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.r_familyStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label com-md-4" })
         <select class="form-control" >
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="1">2</option>
         <option value="1">3</option>
         </select>
         </div>
```

How Validate my dropdownlist? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Use jquery to validate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Bootstrap has styles that can be used to indicate to a user which fields are invalid, it has no way to actually perform the actual verification. From my own experience I would suggest [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) as a possible option that can work very nicely with Bootstrap.